# PHP 7 - Multiple defaults

Tags: php, php-7

I've inherited a piece of code that's something like this:

```
        case 'apple':
        default:
            echo "Apple";
                break;

        case 'banana':
        default:
            echo "Banana";
                break;

        case 'cherry':
            echo "Cherry";
                break;
```

Rather strange syntax!

I didn't actually realize you could have multiple defaults. Or that the code above would even work. Anyway, glossing over that, whilst checking the syntax, it seems this structure will break with PHP7 (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php )

```
7.0.0   Multiple default cases will raise a E_COMPILE_ERROR error.
```

Is that right and does that mean this piece of code would simply not run on PHP7?

Comment: you only need one default. That is why it is called default.. right? that code is horribly wrong.

Comment: @Gogol yes! Exactly.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/DcgCW

Comment: @PaulCrovella True - it's handy to have this documented on SO though.

Comment: It's a good question, not only but also because PHP behaves differently from what is written in the manual. Really no need to downvote.

Comment: There's a [PHP RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/switch.default.multiple) that describes this.

Comment: I agree, this is a good question.

Comment: @PaulCrovella PHP claims a syntax error but it doesn't. It's totally strange behaviour and totally valid to ask about it. The docs are obviously not 100% correct. It's trivial to try it? Yes, but it doesn't explain the bahviour.

Comment: @PaulCrovella I'm talking about a syntax error in PHP 5 which it claims to throw but it doesn't actually. Please read the attached links by me and Darragh.

Comment: @PaulCrovella OP obviously has code from PHP 5 which he suspects is going to break in PHP 7. The specs found here https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/11-statements.md#labeled-statements do not allow more than 1 default, again, please read the things carefully before argueing.

Comment: @PaulCrovella "it seems this structure will break with PHP7" <- This sentence is in `future progressive` and means that the event is not finished in that moment in time (now) and something different/prior to that is still in effect. Which version of PHP do you think he is running the script without getting compile errors???? Please stop bugging me, you are very narrow minded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In prior versions:

> The spec claims the following is a syntax error, while PHP will
>   execute it with the last default block being taken.

See https://wiki.php.net/rfc/switch.default.multiple

Starting from PHP 7, it will throw a compile error.

It does not make sense to define multiple defaults.

Answer (score 2):

You could specify multiple defaults but it never actually worked - only the last one was used, the rest was ignored.

The code you posted will output *Banana* in PHP 4 - 5 and end on a compile error in PHP 7: https://3v4l.org/JsocB

To fix the code while maintaining original behavior, remove all but the last `default` statement.